# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

[ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) has posted this same question on the meta of all the other sites undergoing elections. He doesn't have a Seasoned Advice account, though, so with his blessing I'm posting this here for everyone to use.

> [Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.
>
> [Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).
>
> The information presented is:
>
> What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.
>
> - Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
> - Up-vote/down-vote ratio
> - Average reputation earned per post
> - Average reputation earned per day.
> - Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.
>
> It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.
>
> The information is presented as is with no commentary.
>
> It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this, I've used it extensively in the other moderator elections (the ones I'm eligible to vote in) and think it's a great help in understanding more about the *actions* of the candidates.

Something seems to be wrong with the question history, though.  It's listing several unnamed questions for both hobodave and myself that lead to 404s.  Even if the questions were deleted, we'd be able to see them.  Is this a known issue?  Maybe someone could let Yi Jiang know about this?  (I'm not sure which sites / rooms he frequents).

Comment: ["The election nominations posts are listed, but any links to them will result in 404"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/478210#478210)

Comment: Those are indeed the elections nominations posts (It'll be more obvious once you add comments to them). Any *direct* links to the nominations post will result in a 404, probably for security reasons. I'm not entirely sure what to make of those activities, but they are there for completeness sake I suppose (I'm not sure what *other* types of activities will generate these 'no title' activities)